# Recompiling System.Web.Optimization to change Cache Headers

Tags: .net, system.web.optimization

I want to recompile System.Web.Optimization to change the cache headers in Bundle.cs (CDN does not like the Vary header), since there appears to be no other way to override the headers. I am able to decompile the source (via Resharper), make the change, and recompile the source just fine but when I add the reference to my project all dependent Nuget packages give an error. Similar to the one below.

*The type 'System.Web.Optimization.IBundleBuilder' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'*

I would rather not have to compile all dependencies. I am also open to other means of overriding the cache headers. HTTPModules, IIS etc.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of recompiling a custom version of bundles I just decided to route bundle requests through a different HttpHandler. A quick replace in the URL allows me to easily get the contents of a bundle and write it out with the cache headers I want. Not the most desirable method, but works.

Not allowing you to set your own headers in the library is a huge over sight. I hope they fix this soon.

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        var response = context.Response;
        var cache = response.Cache;

        var path = request.Url.LocalPath;
        var bundlesPath = "~/" + path.Substring(path.IndexOf("mypath"));
        bundlesPath = bundlesPath.Replace("mypath", "bundle");


        Bundle bundle = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor(bundlesPath);
        var bundleContext = new BundleContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), BundleTable.Bundles, bundlesPath);
        var bundleResponse = bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(bundleContext);

        cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1));
        cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0));
        cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);

        // This handler is called whenever a file ending 
        // in .sample is requested. A file with that extension
        // does not need to exist.
        response.ContentType = bundleResponse.ContentType;
        response.Write(bundleResponse.Content);
    }
```